# set opt-level inside library with rust

Tags: rust

In rust release builds default to `opt-level = 3`. This isn't the intended behavior in a lot of cases. Depending on the library this can significantly increase the binary size, while possibly being slower than `opt-level = 2`. I found an option to override these defaults for the final project using the library:

```
[profile.release.package.my_package]
opt-level = 2
```

In many cases the library author knows best at which optimization level the library should be build by default and so it would make sense for the library itself to be able to override this default. I tried to use:

```
[profile.release]
opt-level = 2
```

inside the libraries `Cargo.toml`, but this didn't have any effect. Is there any way to get this to work, or is this something only the final project can do? Is there a way for more fine granular optimization levels e.g. per file or would this require each file to be placed inside a separate library?

Comment: No, the final binary is in charge to decide. Its author knows the best what they want for it. No library can usually know what is the best opt-level for all settings, this can at most be a recommendation.

Comment: I would simply want to override the default set by rust. If a user still want's to override these things he is free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

`opt-level` is part of a Cargo [profile](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html), which controls the behavior of the compiler. The profile is chosen at build time, from the default profiles, any end-user custom profiles, and any [overrides](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#overrides) set by the `Cargo.toml` used to execute the build. Overrides you set in your library's `Cargo.toml` only affect binaries that belong to the library.

If you choose to distribute a dynamic library, you can set the `opt-level` for the distributed shared object/DLL, but this prevents your library's functions from being inlined in user code.

Your best option (as regards `opt-level`) is to advise users (in docs, README or elsewhere) that `opt-level = 3` produces code bloat, and suggest using `opt-level = 2` instead. A popular project that provides analogous advice is Bevy, which [suggests setting the `opt-level` to make debug builds faster](https://bevyengine.org/learn/book/getting-started/setup/#compile-with-performance-optimizations).

---

> Depending on the library this can significantly increase the binary size, while possibly being slower than `opt-level = 2`.

If you're concerned about final binary size, there are other ways to reduce the amount of generated code. You might recommend that users enable [LTO](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#lto), which can reduce code size at the cost of additional compile time.

Another common culprit is generics, and specifically the monomorphization of very long functions. If performance permits, you may choose to make generic functions stubs that call a common, non-generic function. For instance:

```rust
fn foo<S: AsRef<str>>(input: S) {
    // Some long, complex function.
    // ...
}
```

Code is generated for every distinct type on which `foo()` is called (`&str`, `String`, `Cow<str>`, etc.). You can reduce the cost of repeated monomorphization by forcing all such calls to follow the same path:

```rust
fn foo<S: AsRef<str>>(input: S) {
    foo_str(input.as_ref());
}

fn foo_str(input: &str) {
    // Complex logic goes here.
    // ...
}
```

This produces very little code for each monomorphization of `foo()`, and all produced functions call into a shared code path, resulting in a smaller binary and possibly better instruction cache usage. YMMV, of course; profile first and focus on the functions that result in the most bloat.